# Java multiple monitor issue

Tags: java, swing, remote-access, multiple-monitors

I am developing an application with three monitors configured with one system. Two monitors are having different display contents which is achieved using java `GraphicsEnvironment` and `GraphicsDevice` classes. Now the third monitor attached to the system is supposed to display the content of one of the first two monitor(either Display0 or Display1) through which the operation could be viewed. (This monitor should work just like how a remote access software works, e.g vnc viewer).

Each graphics device has own JFrame to display, I am displaying my JComponents to these devices, but I am clueless with this third monitor how to handle. Does Java provide any API or mechanism so that I can show the operations on one monitor into another monitor? Any idea/insight will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Nikki

Answer (score 0):

Read-only access isn't very hard. Let's call the 2 JFrames you have frameA and frameB and the frame on the new monitor frameC.

You can render the contents of A or B into C as follows:

```
JFrame frameC = new JFrame();
Container cont = c.getContentPane();
cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JLabel lab = new JLabel();
cont.add(new JScrollPane(lab), BorderLayout.CENTER);
jFrameC.setSize(800,600);
```

Then, periodically, run this code:

```
JFrame f = frameA; // or frameB
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(f.getWidth(), f.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
f.paint(g);
g.dispose();
lab.setIcon(new IconImage(bi));
```

If you actually want to control frameA/B from frameC, that gets a good bit harder. I would probably start with [java.awt.Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html). Java2S has some [examples demonstrating the use of Robot](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/0980__Robot.htm).

The hardest part of controling the "remote" frame will be translating mouse events in frameC to frameA/B. You'll need to calculate the offset into the image, then translate that back to the content pane of the other frame.

Note: [SwingUtilities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) has several methods to help with translating coordinates.